# Use the lastest affected data in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this list object that I return:

```
return ({
    name: data.name,
    request: {
      method: methodLine[index].method.toUpperCase(),
      header: data.request.header,
      description: data.request.description,
    },
    response: [
      {
        originalRequest: request
      }
    ],
})
```

And I want to use the data stored in the object `request` while calling it in the `response array` in the same `return statement`. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Can you be clearer? What I understand right now is that you want the exact same data of your `request` object into your `response[0].originalRequest` one.

Comment: @iArcadia yes that's what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in the return statement, you can use the comma operator to declare two expressions, the first is a variable declaration to declare `request` and the second is the returned object using `request`:

```js
const test = () => {
  return (request = 'hello', {
    request,
    response: [{
      originalRequest: request
    }]
  })
}

console.log(test());
```

> However, this is not so readable and I suggest splitting this into a proper variable declaration before the return statement.

```js
const test = () => {
  const request = 'hello';
  return {
    request,
    response: [{
      originalRequest: request
    }]
  }
}

console.log(test());
```